# Stewart Platform Formulas

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

What kind of formulas/equations are commonly used to implement Stewart Platforms in electronics and mechanics?

Using a co-ordinate system, how would you determine the position of each actuator, etc?

Comment: What's a Stewart platform?

Comment: This seems awfully broad. Can you add some information about the specific practical problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @OlinLathrop - It's typically a triangular platform above a flipped triangular platform, with 6 linear actuators between the two of them, capable of 6DOF motion simulation. They're used commonly in flight simulators. @ MartinRand - I voted to close this question not because it's unclear, but because it's too broad. The formulas and equations come from physics, statics, dynamics, and kinematics. It's a great engineering problem, but a 'list of equations' with no explanation of what they are, how to use them, etc. would be a meaningless answer. To explain everything - a textbook. See below.

Answer (score 4):

A Stewart platform is a type of parallel manipulator with (usually) 6 prismatic actuators.

For controlling the platform, you would firstly need the inverse kinematics equations for this type of manipulator. These would give you the actuator states needed to place the end effector, i.e. the platform in our case, in a certain position. [This paper](http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~fszufnar/publications/Szufnarowski2013.pdf) might be worth looking at.

I don't know how much experience you have in robotics, but I would also recommend Introduction to Robotics: Analysis, Control, Applications by S. B. Niku if you can get your hands on it.